# Train on AWS using GPU not CPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, gpu

I just launched an AWS P2 instance trying to train a model. However it seems to be using the CPU to train not the GPU. How can I force it to train using the GPU not the CPU?

```
$ nano ~/.keras/keras.json says this
{     "image_dim_ordering": "th",     
"epsilon": 1e-07,
     "floatx": "float32",     
"backend": "tensorflow"     }
```

I am getting a message "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime."

I then changed

```
$ nano ~/.keras/keras.json says this
{     "image_dim_ordering": "th",     
"epsilon": 1e-07,
     "floatx": "float32",     
"backend": "theano"     }
```

It's training, however very slowly and seems to be using the cpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is add a gpus flag!

python cnn_homework_solution.py --gpus 0,1